# How do you apply the same function to a subset of arguments passed into a function?

Tags: r

Consider the following function:

```
tmp_fn <- function(a, x, y, z){
    if (is.vector(x)) x <- matrix(x, nrow = 1)
    if (is.vector(y)) y <- matrix(y, nrow = 1)
    if (is.vector(z)) z <- matrix(z, nrow = 1)

    ... do other stuff

}
```

Is there a better way instead of typing out multiple if statements to convert each of (possible) vectors `x, y, z` into row vectors. Or more generally, apply the same function to a subset of the arguments passed into a function when it is called?

Comment: What if x, y, or z is a list?  You want to turn a list into a matrix?  That could get ugly.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that. I wasn't planning on passing lists in but I suppose to be precise, in this particular case I should ensure it's not a list before coercing to matrix. The idea is just to convert these arguments to matrices so that I can always use matrix algebra in the body of the function. (The question isn't specifically about this particular function though.)

Comment: I think the best way to do this would be to pass matrices into the function to begin with. Then immediately check the structure with `is.matrix` and accept/reject accordingly. If you want a matrix in the function, only accept matrices into it.  That would be my recommendation.

Comment: That does seem sensible.